# Joining two Models in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

I have a Location model and an Answer model and I'm trying to join the two, so that when an Answer is created, it is associated with the Location.
I have added in the appropriate has_one and belongs_to associations, added a migration to add Locations id to the Answer table.

Trouble is when an Answer gets created, the 'location_id' is nil.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my files:

Location Model

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'Geoip-rails'
  has_one :answer

  def self.get_location
geoip = GeoIP.new("lib/GeoLiteCity.dat")
    l = Location.new
    l.city = geoip.country('78.151.144.93').city_name
    l.save
  end 
end
```

Answer Model

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :choice
  has_one :question, :through => :choice
end
```

Add location to Answers migration

```
class AddLocationToAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :answers, :location_id, :integer
    add_index :answers, :location_id
  end
end
```

Questions controller - Answer action

```
def answer
  @choice = Choice.find(params[:id])
  @location = Location.get_location
  @answer = Answer.create(:question_id => @choice.question_id, :choice_id => @choice.id)
  redirect_to questions_url
end
```

**Update:**

I have now changed around the association from Mischa's comments.

Now in the console I can do this and join the Models:

```
1.9.3-p392 :013 > a = Answer.last
Answer Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" ORDER BY "answers"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Answer id: 13, question_id: 1, choice_id: 2, created_at: "2013-07-05 09:50:28", updated_at: "2013-07-05 09:50:28", location_id: nil> 
1.9.3-p392 :014 > a.location
 => nil 
1.9.3-p392 :015 > a.location = Location.last
Location Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" ORDER BY "locations"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Location id: 25, lat: nil, lon: nil, city: "London", created_at: "2013-07-05 09:50:28", updated_at: "2013-07-05 09:50:28"> 
1.9.3-p392 :016 > a
 => #<Answer id: 13, question_id: 1, choice_id: 2, created_at: "2013-07-05 09:50:28", updated_at: "2013-07-05 09:50:28", location_id: 25> 
1.9.3-p392 :017 >
```

I've tried achieving this in 'answer' action in the controller as follows:

```
@answer = Answer.create(:question_id => @choice.question_id, :choice_id => @choice.id, :location_id => @location.id)
```

But :location_id => @location.id give me an error:

undefined method `id' for true:TrueClass

I don't know how to combine the two models in the controller

**Solved**

For anyone interested. My get_location method wasn't doing what it should. I had to call the object l after it had been saved. 5 hours of head banging and all that was needed was 'l'.

```
def self.get_location
geoip = GeoIP.new("lib/GeoLiteCity.dat")
 l = Location.new
 l.city = geoip.country('78.151.144.93').city_name
 l.save!
 l
end
```

Comment: The foreign key should be in the other table (the model that has `belongs_to`). So either you have add `answer_id` to locations or you should change to `Location has_one :answer` and `Answer belongs_to :location`. I suggest the last option, cause it's easier. Your code may have more problems, but this is the first thing I noticed.

Comment: Thanks Mischa - I've done the last option.